# How I can restart windows PC using UWP app?

Tags: c#, windows, uwp

I tried to restart windows PC using Process shell code in UWP app. But it does nothing. I don't want to use desktop bridge and create exe for my UWP app. My requirement is to host this UWP app in store and when anybody opens the app there will be simple button which will restart the system.
Note : the app is not this simple it just one use case.

Comment: What if you cant? UWP was written to disallow certain behaviors for security reasons.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. The whole point of UWP apps is that they are restricted in what they can do, and not being allowed to restart the machine they're installed on is one of the restrictions.